# plain text instead of HTML element in Django

Tags: html, django, function

I have a model like this:

```
class FirstOne(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pretext = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    first = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    last = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and then another model is like this:

```
class SecondOne(models.Model):
    def first_one_pretext(self):
        pk = self.firstone.pk
        a = FirstOne.objects.filter(pk=pk).get()
        return a.pretext
```

And when I do this, I always get a "html element" and not the plain text stored in pretext of the object. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the text from HTML to plain text using javascript – by getting the element via querySelector, then add to the variable ".innerText" or ".textContent":

```
let theVariable = document.querySelector("#text").innerText
```

Where you can then return this with a form (with an  of type="hidden") and set the value of "theVariable" and retrieve that (value) in views.py.

Comment: I do not use the return of the function in a template where I can then use javascript. I pass it to another function, where I need only the plain text, not a html element. I already tried smth like `soup = BeautifulSoup(a.pretext, 'html.parser')` and `soup.input['value']` but that doesnt work well either...

Comment: Oh ok can you show the function you use, and your views.py